# Javascript function doesn't do all instructions

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid

I have a problem with javascript function. I'm using `onSubmit` in my html file. And it get me "we are in" alert, but whene I comment first `alert("we are in")` and uncomment second one (`alert ("here")`) there is no action, no alert shows.

```
function checkCheckbox() {
  alert ("we are in");
  var i=document.getElementById.value('iii');
  //alert ("here");
  for(var k = 0; k < i; k++){
    var id_lista="lista"+k;
    if(document.getElementById('id_lista')!= null){
        var ile_t="ile_t_opis_"+k;
        var ile_t_opis=document.getElementById.value('ile_t');
        var ile=0;
        for(var m=0; m < ile_t_opis; m++){
            var opis="opis_"+k+"_"+m;
            if (document.getElementById('opis').checked==true){
                ile++;
            }
        }
        if (ile==0){
            alert ("You didn\'t choose any of the checkboxes!");
            return false;
        } else {    
            return true;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hit the F12 key and check for errors in your browser developer console.

Comment: Should be `document.getElementById('iii').value;`.

Comment: The line after the first 'alert' is wrong. As @Pointy points out, you should be able to use the developer console in Firefox or Chrome to help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of problems in your code. Especially in the way you use document.getElementById(). In many instances of your code, you create a string literal inside the call, rather than the evaluated value of the variable you declared to hold the needed id. I have re-written your code with the issues fixed. Here's the re-writted version:

```
 function checkCheckbox() {
  alert ("we are in");
  var i=document.getElementById('iii').value;
  alert ("here");
  for(var k = 0; k < i; k++){
    var id_lista="lista"+k;
    if(document.getElementById(id_lista)!= null){
        var ile_t="ile_t_opis_"+k;
        var ile_t_opis=document.getElementById(ile_t).value;
        var ile=0;
        for(var m=0; m < ile_t_opis; m++){
            var opis="opis_"+k+"_"+m;
            if (document.getElementById(opis).checked==true){
                ile++;
            }
        }
        if (ile==0){
            alert ("You didn't choose any of the checkboxes!");
            return false;
        } else {    
            return true;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think *all* the `getElementById()` calls are wrong in one way or another.

Comment: exactly, right, pointy. Using string literals rather than the declared variables